# Woocommerce REST API get products by attributes

Tags: rest, filter, attributes

Using the woocommerce v3 API, I want to filter/get products by attributes.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com/products?filter[pa_color]=green&fields=id,attributes
```

How can I hook/modify the API so it will be able to perform such query?

Comment: @CharlieFish for those who are familer with woo REST API, they understand the question on the spot...

But anyway, I will take your tip and re edit.

Thank you.

Comment: @CharlieFish looking at your profile it seems that you are only looking to "promote" yourself on stack by answering this way, as there are many other question you answered that are "how to's".

If you don't know the answer, it's better to stay quiet...

Comment: Just going through review queues my friend and helping make sure the community gets good answers that help everyone. There is a reason stack overflow has those guidelines. I always try to comment when going through review queues to help improve the content on SO. :)

Comment: @CharlieFish as i said - if you are not familer with woo REST API than you cant really understand the question.

guess you downvoted because of that...too bad.

just to clerify, it is not a "how to" question or a guide seek.

it is a pure ask for a hook isnide the API itself.

keep up the "good work" !

Answer (score 1):

As this documented in [Woocommerce Rest API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products) (that have poor documentation actually), It accepts the attribute slug/taxonomy name:

```
example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=pa_compatible-for&attribute_term=249
```

It works like a charm.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

According to  [API](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products) you should be able to sort by attribute. "Limit result set to products with a specific attribute, e.g. ?attribute=pa_color." Passing in the attribute as a normal parameter.

Comment: first, I thank you for the effort, though you reffered me to the new API which is based on WP-REST and not to API v3 as I mentioned... anyway - that's the real spirit of stack! thanks again :-)

Comment: @user3368504 You are trying to use Legacy v3? http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html

Comment: I'm not trying to use...I am using. The new API was introduced not so long ago and I find the legacy v3 much more suitable and efficient than the new API which is based on WP-REST. Anyway, I set yesterday and a few hours ago managed to solve my problem - so dont break your head.. I got it to work :) thanks for your time and help

Comment: @user3368504 Ok. Just for future reference if anyone else has this problem if you could submit and answer for how you fixed it just so if future people have the same issue they can reference it. That would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

you should search by attribute and attribute_term, it works for me in v3.

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=55

'pa_color' is the slug of the attribute, you can find it by this link:

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes

'55' is color or value id (it's black here), you can get this id by this link:

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes/1/terms?per_page=99

'1' is the attribute id, you can get it from previous link (attributes link).

Comment: This works, however do you know if filtering multiple attributes is supported? e.g https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=55&attribute=pa_size&attribute_term=90 ?

Comment: it is supported, I used to filter by size and color same as the link you provide.